# Java RMI NoClassDefFoundError (development on Netbeans IDE)

Tags: java, rmi

I'm a student, and I'm trying to write an RMI application.

I have 3 separate projects:

- One is Server Side
- One is Common (include Interface and Entities to reflect with Database Structure)
- One is Client

and I write it on Netbeans IDE.

When I start server I receive a printstack error like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rmi/cosmetic/Interfaces/ICategories
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at Server.ServerSide.main(ServerSide.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmi.cosmetic.Interfaces.ICategories
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 13 more
Java Result: 1
```

> rmi/cosmetic/Interfaces/ICategories

is the path of file Interface Categories, it has been contained in Common Project for both of 2 sides client and server

I have no idea about this issue. I try to set classpath on my windows but it didn't work.

Can someone please help me?

Some images, to make it clear

http://upanh.7nghiep.com/vgo-images/vgo.vn-qIntT.jpg

http://upanh.7nghiep.com/vgo-images/vgo.vn-jaJw0.jpg

upanh.7nghiep.com/vgo-images/vgo.vn-RvxIo.jpg

upanh.7nghiep.com/vgo-images/vgo.vn-DvuMt.jpg

upanh.7nghiep.com/vgo-images/vgo.vn-OI9rL.jpg

Comment: Are your client, server and common classes packaged in 3 separate jars?

Comment: see example http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2012/01/a-simple-java-rmi-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   rmi.cosmetic.Interfaces.ICategories

There's your problem right there. Your Registry or your client can't find that class. It needs to be on their CLASSPATH.

Comment: How to let their know CLASSPATH? i was set on windows enviroment but i dont know why it cant be find

Comment: Thank you i solve it by define classpath in windows enviroment